# Positioning a div over a table row

Tags: html, html-table, rows

How can I position a div over a table row inside a table? This div would be the size of the row it is over so that it covers it completely. Any help is appreciated.

This is what I have:

```html
<table>
  <tr style="position: relative;">
    <td>
      <div class="picturebox">
        <img src="img/avatar/avatar1.jpg">    
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="agentname">
      Peter Edwards    
    </td>
    <td>
      45
    </td>
    <td>
      7
    </td>
    <td>
      $2,900 USD
    </td>
    <td>
      $1,100 USD
    </td>
    <td>
      $4,000 USD
    </td>
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #eee; width:100%; top: 10px;">Test</div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hmmm... weird when I try this here it works... must have another element where this table is messing with my positioning...

Comment: Please post your code and what you're tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You just put it over it?

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <div>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

Comment: ^ Yep, just envelop - if I'm understanding the Q correctly.